# React js компонент

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Пытаюсь воплотить вот это приложение http://todomvc.com/examples/react/#/
Имею два компонента, NoteList где имеется сам input и откуда должны по идее создаваться записи, и сама запись Note. Получается в функции onBtnClickHandler() я пытаюсь возвратить статью , таким образом создать ее , но ничего не происходит. В чем проблема?

```js
class NoteList extends Component {


    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            value: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.onBtnClickHandler = this.onBtnClickHandler.bind(this);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="NodeList_div">
                <button onClick={this.onBtnClickHandler}>X</button>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}/>
                <div className="nodelist_note"></div>
                <div className="nodelist_footer">
                    2 items left
                    <button>X</button>
                    <button>X</button>
                    <button>X</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        )
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        console.log(this.state.value);
    }
    onBtnClickHandler() {
        return (<div>
            <Note />
        </div>)

    }
}
export default NoteList
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, стоит разобраться с кодом и его поведением. Начнем с метода обработки клика:

```
onBtnClickHandler() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Note />
      </div>
   );
}
```

Метод возвращает элемент `Note` обернутый в `div` тэг. Ничего сложного, на первый взгляд. Но куда возвращается этот элемент? Правильно - никуда.

Значит нужно организовать хранилище. Напрашивается сразу же `state` компонента в качестве хранилища, так и  поступим, будем хранить там. Так как в примере для создания `Note` компонента ничего не нужно (я имею в виду `props`), то достаточно хранить просто цифру с количеством записей, но мы пойдем дальше и будем хранить массив, в массиве будут ключи. Перепишем конструктор:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    value: '',
    notes: [], // в начале будет пустой массив
  }

  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  this.onBtnClickHandler = this.onBtnClickHandler.bind(this);
}
```

Следующим на очереди будет метод рендеринга компонента, так как у нас появилась коллекция неких элементов, значит можно использовать метод `map` для прохода по массиму и отрисовке отдельных компонент.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="NodeList_div">
      <button onClick={this.onBtnClickHandler}>X</button>
      <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value}/>
      <div className="nodelist_note">
        {this.state.notes.map((note) => { return <Note key={note} />; })}
      </div>
      <div className="nodelist_footer">
        2 items left
        <button>X</button>
        <button>X</button>
        <button>X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Здесь мы добавили простую конструкцию прохода по массиву и возвращения новой коллекции:

```
{this.state.notes.map((note) => { return <Note key={note} />; })}
```

Обратите внимание на добавленное свойство `key` - если его не добавить, то React это не понравится и получите ошибки в консоли из-за того, что отрисовываете список значений и у них нет уникального поля `key`. Об этом можно почитать тут: [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). Теперь можно переписать обработчик клика на кнопку (это всего лишь пример):

```
onBtnClickHandler() {
  const oldNotes = this.state.notes; // получить массив из state
  const element = oldNotes.length; // вычислим длину массива
  oldNotes.push(++element) // добавим в массив новое значение
  this.setState({ notes: oldNotes }); // запишем новое значение в state
}
```

Вызов метода `setState` и изменение значения  в `state` вызовет ререндеринг компонента, то есть перерисовку на форме, это в свою очередь обновит список выводимых значений в `div` блоке `nodelist_note`.